# Order Success Page in Magento needs to be https:// and not www

Tags: html, css, magento, ssl, google-trusted-stores

Is there a way to make sure that the order success page in magento outputs the page in https:// instead of just wwww.

I have SSL on my site and I need the order confirmation page to be in https:// for Google Trusted Stores to work on my site.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to modify your payment controller so when you get a successful payment response from your gateway it then has a like the following;

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Take a look at PayPal's standard payment controller and compare to whatever you are using.